# Logging to two different .log files

Tags: python, logging

I would like to put the request logs in different files. Unfortunately, the code below actually creates 2 different .log files, but all the logs end up in the first and the second is completely empty. Can basicConfig be set up so that logs land in different files?

```
import logging
import time

def example_request_handler(name):
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO,
        format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
        handlers=[
            logging.FileHandler(f"{name}.log"),
            logging.StreamHandler()])
    logging.info(name)

example_request_handler("first_request1")
example_request_handler("secound_request2")
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to the first log to go to the first file, the second to the second file, the third to the first file, etc.?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once logging handlers are added to the `logging.basicConfig` they will still remain as they are even after you reconfigure them.

In **Python3.8**, there was a new `force` argument introduced in the [`logging.basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#logging.basicConfig). If this keyword argument is specified as true, any existing handlers attached to the root logger are removed and closed, before carrying out the configuration as specified by the other arguments.

That would make your function as -

```
import logging
import time

def example_request_handler(name):
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO,
        force = True,
        format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
        handlers=[
            logging.FileHandler(f"{name}.log"),
            logging.StreamHandler()])
    logging.info(name)

example_request_handler("first_request1")
example_request_handler("second_request2")
```

Above should log the `second_request2` only in the second file.

Please note that removing/adding new logging handlers for every new log is generally a bad idea. If you want to log into `n` different files, then consider initializing different loggers for them and keep a mapping of loggers in a manager function which your individual logging functions can use.